# Azure AD B2C "setting.retryLimit" not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've changed the setting in "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" for the password reset flow by adding:

```
<Item Key="setting.retryLimit">5</Item>
```

in the Metadata section.

However, it doesn't seem to work - the limit is still the default of 3 when I try and send invalid codes.

Does this setting apply in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setting.retryLimit` defines the maximum number of times that the validation technical profiles for a self-asserted technical profile can fail.

I believe the verification throttle is an internal configuration that can't be changed.