# How to change maximum number for retries for a self-asserted step in azure ad b2c custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policies and i'm getting an error "User has exceeded the maximum number for retries for a self-asserted step.". When i counted it is happened after seven incorrect. Is there any way to change this number like if i need to set it up as 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setting.retryLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata) controls the number of times a user can try to provide the data that is checked against a validation technical profile . For example, a user tries to sign-up with an account that already exists and keeps trying until the limit reached.

The verification throttle is an internal configuration that can't be changed.

See a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698256/azure-ad-b2c-setting-retrylimit-not-working).